# Strange FOV error in laser_scan_matcher using a cloud

Tags: ros, icp, pointcloud, laser-scan-matcher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to use laser_scan_matcher with a PointCloud2 made by 2 opposite LaserScans, so I have a 360º pointcloud.

**Is it possible?**
When I run laser_scan_matcher i get the following error: (where FOV remains negative with different values)

```
Error in scan matching Strange FOV: -0.475675 rad = -27.254197 deg
```

I've tried to find the origin of the problem,

In the CSM laser_data.c code you can find it comes from this min and max theta:

```
196 double min_fov = deg2rad(20.0); 
197 double max_fov = 2.01 * M_PI;
198 double fov = ld->max_theta - ld->min_theta;
199 if( fov < min_fov || fov > max_fov) {
200   sm_error("Strange FOV: %f rad = %f deg \n", fov, rad2deg(fov));
201   return 0;
202 }
```

And from laser_scan_matcher.cpp:

```
532     ldp->theta[i] = atan2(cloud->points[i].y, cloud->points[i].x);
533     ldp->cluster[i]  = -1;
534   }
535 
536   ldp->min_theta = ldp->theta[0];
537   ldp->max_theta = ldp->theta[n-1];
```

So I suppose that the indexes 0 and n-1 of my cloud are not the right ones or when I create the cloud with the two LaserScans I am doing something wrong (even the cloud looks fine in rviz)

Anyone know a way to solve this?

thanks in advance!

**Edit: How i construct the pointcloud**

I have two subscribers to LaserScans, in their callbacks:

```
laser_projector_.projectLaser(*msg, cloud);
pcl_ros::transformPointCloud (base_frame_, cloud, cloudX_, tf_listener_);
```

When both messages have arrived and have been transformed I add them doing this:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> all_data(cloud1_.data);
all_data.reserve(cloud1_.data.size() + cloud2_.data.size());
all_data.insert(all_data.end(), cloud2_.data.begin(), cloud2_.data.end());

PointCloud2_msg_.header.seq      = counter_++;
PointCloud2_msg_.header.stamp    = ros::Time::now();
PointCloud2_msg_.header.frame_id = base_frame;
PointCloud2_msg_.fields          = cloud1_.fields;
PointCloud2_msg_.is_bigendian    = cloud1_.is_bigendian;
PointCloud2_msg_.point_step      = cloud1_.point_step;
PointCloud2_msg_.row_step        = cloud1_.row_step;
PointCloud2_msg_.is_dense        = cloud1_.is_dense;
PointCloud2_msg_.height          = cloud1_.height;
PointCloud2_msg_.width           = cloud1_.width+cloud2_.width;
PointCloud2_msg_.data            = all_data;
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29953/strange-fov-error-in-laser_scan_matcher-using-a-cloud/) by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 843 on 2012-03-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure that your cloud is ordered sequentially - points[0] should correspond to the minimum-angle beam, and points[n-t] should be the maximum-angle beam.

You are getting a negative field of view (-27 deg), so that points to something wrong with the limits. How are you constructing the point cloud?

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2012-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on 2012-03-19**:
I have edited my question to show how i construct this pointcloud. thanks!

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2012-03-19**:
Make sure cloud 1 is on the right, and cloud2 on the left. Cloud1 should go from -pi to 0, and cloud 2 from 0 to pi. Can you verify the atan2 angles: cloud1.points[0] -> -pi, cloud2.points[] -> pi?

**Comment by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on 2012-03-19**:
It seems that cloud1 goes from ~-80 to ~80 through 0 and cloud2 from ~100 to ~-100 through 180 where it changes to -180. I suppose I should shift to get something like -pi..0 and 0..pi. thanks!